# Increase or decrease vertices in circle after working with it?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

Is it possible to change the resolution of a circle after working with it so that it has a greater or fewer number of vertices? If this is not normally possible, but there is a workflow that keeps it editable, that also counts.

Comment: related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/is-there-any-way-to-edit-parameters-for-an-object-after-it-is-created

Comment: The goal of this question was more of asking if there exists either a feature or an add-on (or if someone wants to write one) that notices that a selection forms a circle and then allows the user to change the number of vertices in that circle. That question may be related but the intents are different and not duplicates.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3259/599, http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3487/599, http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8157/599.

Comment: You could try the decimate modifier, it is not very controllable though.

Comment: In addition to what @david said, you can use [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/11035/42264) to select every other edge loop.

Answer (score 11):

### For the creation of a primitive

**Yes, and no**
You can change the settings right after creating any of the primitives, by pressing <kbd>f6</kbd>.
After you do anything else, (besides moving around the view) the settings are gone with no way to get back to them.

### Editing loop count in a circle

To reduce the number of edges.
In edit mode, select every other loop by <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd> (use <kbd>shift</kbd> to add to the selection). Then press <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>delete</kbd> and choose *Edge Loop*. Do the same for the edges on the other axis.

[image: Delete menu]

To increase the number of edges.
Delete the bottom and top vertex (where all the loops meet). Select everything with <kbd>A</kbd>, then press <kbd>W</kbd> and choose *Subdivide Smooth*. The loops will get wavy, to fix that select them with <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd> then press <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>. Which will flatten them along the Z axis.

To fix the holes in the top of the circle, select the top edge loop, and extrude it along the Z axis. Then scale to 0, and remove doubles. Do the same for the bottom of the circle.

Answer (score 10):

### For Mesh Circle:

While in the 3D View window, enter Edit Mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) and select all vertices (<kbd>A</kbd>) and click <kbd>W</kbd> and select "Subdivide Smooth", then open the Tool Shelf (<kbd>T</kbd>), and  change the "Number of cuts" field to match your needs.

### For Curve Circle:

While in the 3D View window, select the Circle, enter Edit Mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) and select all vertices (<kbd>A</kbd>) and click <kbd>W</kbd> and select "Subdivide", then open the Tool Shelf (<kbd>T</kbd>), and  change the "Number of cuts" field to match your needs.

Comment: I edited my post to make it more clear, as I see you mistook "after creating it" to mean "directly after adding it to the scene."

Comment: Ok, I changed it; It should now work.

Comment: For the Mesh Circle section, mention that that is for adding vertices and that you should play with the smoothness slider.

Comment: It's already set to 1, by default, if you use subdive smooth

Comment: Ah, I missed that you said Subdivide Smooth. Feel free to clean up comments and I'll do the same.

Comment: Well, clicking `W` didn't seem to do anything except change the selection behavior... And now I seem to be unable to drag-select anything in edit mode.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the Loop Tools add-on that comes with Blender. It got me better results than Subdivide Smooth.

1) Add LoopTools to Blender (`Ctrl-Alt-U`, `Add-ons` tab, search `LoopTools`, check the checkbox and save)

2) Select your Circle Loop

3) Subdivide by pressing `W` and clicking in `Subdivide`

4) Select the number of cuts of your choosing in the Operator Panel (`F6`)

5) While having the loop selected, Press `Circle` in the Loop Tools section in the Tools menu (`T`)

[image]

You should have a perfectly round circle now:

[image]

The process of deleting vertices from the circle should be even easier than that. Just delete the undesired vertices, select the loop, then click the `Circle` button again.

Answer (score 3):

#### Decrease the number of vertices

Select an edge loop

Menu: Select / Checker Deselect

[image]

<kbd>X</kbd> Dissolve vertices

[image]

After that you could remove the vertices which only subdivide edges by selecting one and <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>  Amount of connecting edges and dissolve again.

Comment: Checker Deselect will not give good results on a UV sphere, thus causing the Dissolve vertices to fail.

Comment: @David I added images of what one could expect by this method, dissolve works.

Comment: Rather [Del] -> Edge Loop, for a typical usage

Comment: @avvi removing an edge loop would keep the vertical edges.

Comment: really smart method.