# increasing amount of side faces on object made from cylinder

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, edit-mode

Is there a way to increase the amount of side faces on a cylinder-like object  after manipulating the object in edit mode other than using subsurf and creasing every single edge? The edges selected on the picture are the ones I'm refering to.

I modeled a now somewhat complex object starting with a simple cylinder, assuming that the amount of faces on the side would be sufficient though there's a need to increase it now.

Also, does the shading method (smooth/flat) affect the model in any way when exporting to other file formats?

[image: unnamed]

Comment: Why do you need to add more edges? Its mode than enough edges for that curve.

Comment: When modeling it's usually easier to use a lower number of edges and so  avoid editing dense meshes like that, and instead use the subsurf modifier to smooth things out. Also see [this question and it's many linked and related questions](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13823/increase-or-decrease-vertices-in-circle-after-working-with-it/13825#comment18697_13823).

Comment: You can select the edge loops and bevel them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mesh Objects in Blender don't have an Edit History that would allow you to edit a parameter somewhere at the start of the Object's life and have that propagate through all other operations to the present. You can't in your example change the tube's vertex count after you've made edits to it.

But it is possible to reconstruct the object quickly with the desired vertex counts. For instance use the Screw Modifier to Lathe the profile around an axis. The Object's *center* can be used as the rotation coordinate or an Empty.

Answer (score 0):

Using bevel along the side isn't quite the cleanest solution though it works when the sharp edges at the bottom and the top won't be modified afterwards.
I am probably going to use subsurf and crease all sharp edges to a maximum.
Thanks for the help