# decrease number of vertices

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, vertices

I modeled a snowmobile in blender. It is for a map in another program and this program (hammer) just allows 10.000 vertices. Is there any way, to get less vertices with not deleting any objects? I want to decrease the number of vertices on the tubes in the back and the metal spring on the front! Do I have to model them again or is there another way? I think I heard of a modifier. Thanks for the answers!

[image]

Comment: It's an issue of different levels of mesh density. Ideally, you want all parts of a model to have approximately the same vertex density.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at your model.
[image: snowmobile model too high poly parts marked]
The places where you can only see black are the densest, and that is where you want to focus on reducing the poly count. In your image that would be the front springs, and some of the pipes in the track assembly. All the rest of the model looks fairly low poly and balanced.

I am going to go in an [manually](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13825/2217) reduce the poly count.  Don't worry about selecting all  the edges, it is quick and easy to reduce the poly count in a cylindrical object like a spring.

I will do the spring, but the exact same process works for the pipes.

Start by selecting every other edge loop around the spring.

1. Select the edge rings along the length of the spring. You can do that with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd>
   [image: edge rings selected]
2. Run *Checker Deselect* on that selection. From the 3D view header *Select* > *Checker Deselect*. If you have a very dense mesh increase the *Skip* amount in the [operator properties](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23048/2217) section of the tool shelf.
3. From the 3D view header *Select* > *Edge Loops*.
4. Press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Edge Loops* to remove all those edges.

Now we must do the loops along the length of the spring. Select this in the exact same way as we did before.
[image: edge loops selected.]

---

An animated gif showing the whole process.
[image: animated gif showing how to select loops and reduce the poly count]

Answer (score 5):

You can try the [Decimate modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/decimate.html). Add it to your object in Object mode (not in Edit mode). You can use the Ratio slider to determine the percentage of the mesh to keep (so 1.0 means original mesh, and 0.0 means it's all gone). Once you're happy with the result, click Apply to permanently alter your mesh. Be sure to write a backup copy to another blend file before you do that ;-)