# How can I add loops cuts to all the parent selection within an object?

Tags: modeling

I have a model, that I have selected specific face loops and I used (Shift G) - > Perimeter, which selected all of the same kinds of face loops around the whole model. I then want to add two loop cuts on one of those face loops, and is it somehow possible for those two loop cuts to be inherited over all of the selected face loops ? This way I can only press Ctrl - R only once, and all of those selections will get the same kind of loops cuts. If there is no way, then I will have to do it manually, and this will be very frustrating, because there is over 30 of those faces, and there is a big chance of missing some. If someone knows a technique to do this in a much faster way, please specify it below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3259/599

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to hide the everything else while your face loops selected.
2. Switch to edge selection mode and select one of the short edges
3. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to select similar and choose Length from the menu to select all the edge rings.
4. Hit <kbd>W</kbd> and select Subdivide from the menu and in the operator panel or by hitting <kbd>F6</kbd> change number of subdivisions to 2 to make 2 edge loops across all the edge rings.

Comment: Thank You! Very good technique. It worked perfectly. I just learned a new thing.